# Get value of last non-NA row per column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `datatable` where each column represents a time series, and I want to grab the last NA value per time series in a column-ordered manner. In my particular use case my data looks like this:

```
a   b     c
1   2     5
1   -17   9
NA  11    4
NA  57    NA
63  NA    NA
```

So out of this I would like to extract:

```
a   b    c
63  57   4
```

How can I accomplish this? So far I only see answers addressing the converse situation of extracting the last non-NA per row rather than per column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the dataset is `data.table`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), subset the non-NA element (`x[!is.na(x)]`) and extract the last element among those with `tail`.

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)],1))]
#   a  b c
#1: 63 57 4
```

Comment: yes. or `apply(df1,2,function(x)x[max(which(!is.na(x)))])`

Comment: @akrun, is it possible to do this by row? output: `5, 9, 4, 57, 63`? (not sure if this merits a new question)

Comment: @RafaelMartins  Probably you need `do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1]  5  9 11 57 63`

Answer (score 11):

For someone wishing to use only base `R`.

```
sapply(df, function(x) x[max(which(!is.na(x)))])
```

2024 alternative:

```
sapply(df, \(x) Find(Negate(is.na), x, right = TRUE))
```

where

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 63),
                 b = c(2, -17, 11, 57, NA),
                 c = c(5, 9, 4, NA, NA))
```