# R: Automated offsetting in a data.frame of different length and full of NaN - determing the closest non-NaN value for every cell in a df

Tags: r, dataframe, nan

i'm stuck. I've tried different approachs but without luck. And could really use some help :)

**Task**
We have a quite large data.frame (dd) of displacement data (slope instability), which is growing with on going monitoring. e.g:

```
> dd[140:148, 1:5]
    UTC.Time Punkt.11 Punkt.13  Punkt.14 Punkt.21
138 2019-09-01 129.6067 110.1933  99.34375 208.1152
139 2019-09-02      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
140 2019-09-03 133.7353 113.6303 102.26286 212.8912
141 2019-09-04 135.0769 114.7829 103.29231 215.2500
142 2019-09-05 136.2333 115.9917 103.80000 216.6250
143 2019-09-06      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
144 2019-09-07      NaN      NaN       NaN 220.8571
145 2019-09-08      NaN 119.5500 107.70000 221.5800
146 2019-09-09 143.5692 121.6769 109.85333 223.7350
147 2019-09-10 144.6364 122.5515 110.67419 224.8308
148 2019-09-11 146.0605 123.7308 111.77105 226.1667
```

Here some more details (as wished by comment)

```
> dput(dd[140:148, 1:5])
    structure(list(UTC.Time = structure(c(18142, 18143, 18144, 18145, 
    18146, 18147, 18148, 18149, 18150), class = "Date"), Punkt.11 = c(133.735294117647, 
    135.076923076923, 136.233333333333, NaN, NaN, NaN, 143.569230769231, 
    144.636363636364, 146.060526315789), Punkt.13 = c(113.630303030303, 
    114.782926829268, 115.991666666667, NaN, NaN, 119.55, 121.676923076923, 
    122.551515151515, 123.730769230769), Punkt.14 = c(102.262857142857, 
    103.292307692308, 103.8, NaN, NaN, 107.7, 109.853333333333, 110.674193548387, 
    111.771052631579), Punkt.21 = c(212.891176470588, 215.25, 216.625, 
    NaN, 220.857142857143, 221.58, 223.735, 224.830769230769, 226.166666666667
    )), row.names = 140:148, class = "data.frame")
```

Now I'd like to **calculate the velocity** as cm/day.
This is straight forward, as I've already have a displacement rate per day and the unit is already cm. So basically it's just the value n (n=now) minus the Value n-1, n-1 beeing the timestep prior. For the sake of it, i'll calculated: (Sn - Sn-1) / (Tn - Tn-1) , S being the cumulated dispacement, T the Date.

I've tried this by

```
    dd_v <- dd # copy dateframe
    dd[,2:ncol(dd)] <- NA # removing everithing but the first col, beeing the date. not pretty, but it works great.
        for (r in 2:nrow(dd)) { # row
                    dd_v[r,2:ncol(dd)] <- abs(
                    dd[r,2:ncol(dd)] - dd[r-1,2:ncol(dd)])  # delta S
                    / (as.numeric(difftime(dd[r,1], dd[r-1,1], units = c("days")))) # delta T
                  }
```

Which is basically fine.
However, now I get for every NaN an other one extra. So I loos quite a lot of Date.

```
> dd_v[140:148, 1:5]
      UTC.Time  Punkt.11  Punkt.13  Punkt.14  Punkt.21
138 2019-09-01 0.9666667 0.7761905 1.0408929 1.3622103
139 2019-09-02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
140 2019-09-03       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
141 2019-09-04 1.3416290 1.1526238 1.0294505 2.3588235
142 2019-09-05 1.1564103 1.2087398 0.5076923 1.3750000
143 2019-09-06       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
144 2019-09-07       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
145 2019-09-08       NaN       NaN       NaN 0.7228571
146 2019-09-09       NaN 2.1269231 2.1533333 2.1550000
147 2019-09-10 1.0671329 0.8745921 0.8208602 1.0957692
148 2019-09-11 1.4241627 1.1792541 1.0968591 1.3358974
```

Therefore, I'd like to interpolate. Meaning:
I'd like to look **for the closest non-NaN value** and calculate the velocity, regarding the greater leap time.

i.e. : *Punkt.13 at 2019-09-08 minus Punkt.13 at 2019-09-05 devided by 3, as three days passed.*

Here I'm stuck.
Can you help me?

What i've tried (conceptually, no need of posting my failed code):

Looking for the lower most entry of the dd (which is beeing filled)
and use the index of this value as n-1 in the calculation of the velocity.
However, i cant get this done without resulting errors unsing

```
#which
#which.max()
```

or

I've tried it also with another for loop

```
library(dplyr)
d <- select(dd, 1, c)
# next step: ged rid of NA
# then calculate
# afterwards left_join(…) the multiple slices.
```

help is very much appreciated!

best
AP

Comment: To make it easier to get you some help, could you share the sample data you are showing using `dput(dd[140:148, 1:5])`?

Comment: sure. see above (edited question)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found kind of a solution, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39935034/14958903).

I've adapted it along the logic of which(dd %in s) to find the index. s beeing the search criteria.

```
sapply(dd, function(x) which(x %in% x[max(which(!is.na(x)))]))
```

Returning the position the last non-NaN value for dd.

```
>sapply(dd, function(x) which(x %in% x[max(which(!is.na(x)))]))
UTC.Time Punkt.11 Punkt.13 Punkt.14 Punkt.21 
       9        9        9        9        9
```

true, the example isn't the best as every columns has en entry in the last row. but I'd like to stick to the example.

For my use, the results then looks like this:

```
for (c in 2:ncol(dd_v)) { #loop whitout first colums (time stamps)
      for ( r in 2:nrow(dd_v)) { #loop of each row, without first one, as initial v is unknown.
        
        rr <- sapply(dd_v[c], function(x) which(x %in% x[max(which(!is.na(x)))]))
    if (length(unlist(rr)) > 1) { # if c is empty (multiple NAs), every entry is a maximum, result therefore > 1 
    rr <- r-1 } # if this is the case, rr sould be the row above
    else {} # if not, leave rr as caluclated
        dd_v[r,c] <- abs(
          (dd[r,c]-dd[rr,c])
          /as.numeric(difftime(dd[r,1], dd[rr,1], units = c("days")))
        ) # calculates velocity
        
      } # ENDE row Loop
    } # ENDE column Loop
```

not a pretty code and certainly not fast (as double for loops), but does the job.

If you have a neater solution, please contribute.