# How to drop last value in multiple columns of different lengths in R (based on group)?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where there is an ID column and 10 columns of data. Each ID has a different number of (non-NA) entries for each column, and I want to remove the first and last entry for each ID for each column. For the first entries, this was not a problem because every ID has their first entries on their respective first row, and thus the following code works:

```
data <- grouped_df(data, vars=c("ID"), drop = group_by_drop_default(data)) 
data <- data %>% slice(-c(1))
```

However, for the last entries, as they cannot be identified by a particular row for each ID, I'm at a loss. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934159/get-value-of-last-non-na-row-per-column-in-data-table) I found that making the data frame into a data.table and using supply, I can copy the very last non-NA entries into a new list, but I don't know how to get that for each ID (group) and I don't know how to remove them from the dataset (or create NAs in their place).

So basically, from the following dataset:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  ID
1:  748 726 743 731 696 786 710 732 802 784  A
2:  707 724 760 728 730 798 668 696 492 341  A
3:   NA 743 754 704 729  26  NA 675  NA  NA  A
4:   NA 740 754 691 708  NA  NA  79  NA  NA  A
5:   NA 739  87  69 463  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
6:   NA 594  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
7:  950 814 878 792 743 796 774 700 826 827  B
8:  402 772 789 823 773 732 796 664 857 889  B
9:   NA 819 812 746 744 706 824 656 760 834  B
10:  NA   3 694 782 702 750 771 677 798 759  B
11:  NA  NA  NA 650 512 835  29 123 303 240  B
12:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 226  NA  NA  NA  NA  B
```

I'd like to remove/replace the last non-NA entry for each column for each ID, resulting in

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  ID
1:  748 726 743 731 696 786 710 732 802 784  A
2:   NA 724 760 728 730 798  NA 696  NA  NA  A
3:   NA 743 754 704 729  NA  NA 675  NA  NA  A
4:   NA 740 754 691 708  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
5:   NA 739  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
6:   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
7:  950 814 878 792 743 796 774 700 826 827  B
8:   NA 772 789 823 773 732 796 664 857 889  B
9:   NA 819 812 746 744 706 824 656 760 834  B
10:  NA  NA  NA 782 702 750 771 677 798 759  B
11:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 835  NA  NA  NA  NA  B
12:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  B
```

I would really appreciate any help I could get with this! I'm fairly new at R and cannot wrap my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
DT <- fread("     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  ID
748 726 743 731 696 786 710 732 802 784  A
707 724 760 728 730 798 668 696 492 341  A
NA 743 754 704 729  26  NA 675  NA  NA  A
NA 740 754 691 708  NA  NA  79  NA  NA  A
NA 739  87  69 463  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
NA 594  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  A
950 814 878 792 743 796 774 700 826 827  B
402 772 789 823 773 732 796 664 857 889  B
NA 819 812 746 744 706 824 656 760 834  B
NA   3 694 782 702 750 771 677 798 759  B
NA  NA  NA 650 512 835  29 123 303 240  B
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 226  NA  NA  NA  NA  B", header = TRUE)
# Add row id
DT[, rowid := .I]
# Melt to long, drop NA-values
DT.melt <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("ID", "rowid"), na.rm = TRUE)
# Set last entry of each group to NA
DT.melt[DT.melt[, .I[.N], by = .(ID, variable)][['V1']], value := NA]
# Cast to wide again, fill missing with NA
dcast(DT.melt, ID + rowid ~ variable, value.var = "value", fill = NA)

#    ID rowid   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
# 1:  A     1 748 726 743 731 696 786 710 732 802 784
# 2:  A     2  NA 724 760 728 730 798  NA 696  NA  NA
# 3:  A     3  NA 743 754 704 729  NA  NA 675  NA  NA
# 4:  A     4  NA 740 754 691 708  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 5:  A     5  NA 739  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 6:  A     6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 7:  B     7 950 814 878 792 743 796 774 700 826 827
# 8:  B     8  NA 772 789 823 773 732 796 664 857 889
# 9:  B     9  NA 819 812 746 744 706 824 656 760 834
#10:  B    10  NA  NA  NA 782 702 750 771 677 798 759
#11:  B    11  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 835  NA  NA  NA  NA
#12:  B    12  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```